# SQL Server to MySQL replication character encoding issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, replication

I've just implemented transactional replication from an MS SQL box over to a MySQL instance, and I'm getting an error where '£' signs are showing up as 'ú'. Replication is using a Unicode ODBC connection to connect to the MySQL instance.

I thought initially it may be something to do with the collations, however I also moved some old data across a linked server via the same ODBC connection before putting in replication, and this data is all fine. In case it matters though, MySQL is set to latin1_swedish_ci collation, and MS SQL is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

This leads me to assume that I've incorrectly configured the replication publication somehow, though I'm somewhat stuck as to which setting it would be.

Comment: Set database to utf8. Make sure the connection character set is set to UTF8. Perform this query: 'SET NAMES utf8;'

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked. I've set both the connection and the table to utf8 (the table using:
ALTER TABLE `MyTable` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
As a result of the table change (I think), it's now not rendering the '£' sign at all, and truncates any data after it. E.g. 'abc£123' comes through as 'abc'.